# Gradle method to determine if a directory contains a Gradle project

Tags: gradle

Is there any Gradle method that determines if a directory contains a Gradle project?

Does a directory contain a project if and only if it contains either a `settings.gradle` or a `settings.gradle.kts`? Are there any other requirements or options? e.g., are any other settings file names acceptable? Are any additional files required? Are any other (sets of) files sufficient?

It would be best if I could call some Gradle method to determine if a directory contains a project, since potential project indicators might change over time (e.g., `settings.gradle.kts` only became valid once the Kotlin DSL was released).

Comment: Relates to https://github.com/gradle/gradle/issues/1994